Is tp-link TL-WN725N usable as an Access Point with RaspAp
How can I use the TP-Link TL-WN725N as an Access Point with RaspAP?
I’m trying to set up my TP-Link TL-WN725N WiFi adapter as an access point using RaspAP on a Raspberry Pi. However, it seems like the adapter cannot transmit. When I switch the network interface in RaspAP to use the TP-Link adapter, the hotspot status always shows as down (red indicator).
I also attempted to configure it manually, but the TP-Link adapter only seems to function as a receiver and not an access point.
Has anyone managed to use this adapter successfully with RaspAP? If not, could you recommend a network adapter that is fully compatible with RaspAP for use as an access point?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

using iw list, does that device include AP in Supported interface modes
